# Play Youtube video in VideoView (Within Application)

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

From past 2-3 weeks I am searching for a way to play youtube video in videoview and I have tried almost all the ways that are posted in stackoverflow. (Almost every... and there are lot I must tell). But none seems working for me.

I even tried android-youtube-player also but that doesn't works for me.

**MY Requirement:**
Play Youtube video in VideoView because I want don't want to open Youtube app(A lot of reasons)

If some one is willing to share a working code than that would be of great help. I have tried almost everything and tired of CODING. Hope someone could help me out here.

Comment: you first extract video ID from your youtube URL of video, then you can play it.

Comment: I think youtube webservice provide rstp links.Android 4.0.4 supports RSTP links.

Comment: Can any one provide me working example

Comment: try this open source sample project: http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

Comment: This thread is too old but just in case check this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-youtube-api-tutorial/)

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned [previously](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/) **you can play youtube videos with open youtube player**.

I have attached the working sample [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5DWvLxzcddHQmhKemxkaW93NTg). (Drive is the best solution pops in to my mind and you can save the rar file by pressing ctrl+s). There you will find two projects.

1. YouTubeTester - the sample app I have done
2. OpenYouTubeActivity - the youtube player that downloaded form [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/)

I have included the jar file of OpenYouTubeActivity project in to my project and if you prefer you can refer the OpenYouTubeActivity project as a library for your project (If you refer the project as a library make sure to remove the jar file.). The downloaded source of OpenYouTubeActivity has been updated as mention in issue [list](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/issues/detail?id=3)

```
VideoStream.java (Line: 30)
change: mUrl = lArgMap.get("url");
to:  mUrl = lArgMap.get("url") + "&signature=" + lArgMap.get("sig");
```

Now back to the sample project.

**Manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.youtubetester"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <!--INTERNET and  ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions are required. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".YouTubeTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_you_tube_test" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- You should include following part orientation is your choice-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**YouTubeTest activity class**

```
package com.youtubetester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity;

public class YouTubeTest extends Activity {

    private Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube_test);
        button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        /*
         * The Youtube URL that we get is something like following.
         * http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J467jzLlDcc
         * We need the last part of the URL or id of the video-J467jzLlDcc **/


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri
                        .parse("ytv://"+"J467jzLlDcc"),
                        YouTubeTest.this,
                        OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(lVideoIntent);
                /*
                 * Please note only the id has been passed and prefix is "ytv" NOT "ytpl"*/
            }
        });
    }


}
```

**Layout - activity_you_tube_test.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".YouTubeTest" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help. Please ask if you have any problems. I don't have a deep understanding about the OpenYouTubeActivity project but I'll be able to help.

Comment: are you sure to run above example in all the device ? or above Android  Api 2.2 ?

Comment: :) Tested on 2.2 and above.

Comment: However I believe you would need the youtube application to be installed on the device?

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal : I didn't test this on such a device.

Comment: how can i find the id if the url of my video is like this :
www.youtube.com/embed/PhNacT_Z34g ?

Comment: @libathos: did you try to split the string and get the id. Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: @saji159: Hi, I know how to split strings I don't know which part of the string is the id. I've tried "PhNacT_Z34g" but it won't work

Comment: @libathos: Your id is PhNacT_Z34g. I tested it using the sample application and it's working.code was as follows ("ytv://"+"PhNacT_Z34g")

Comment: @saji159 It's working? I've just tried it and i says that it can't play the video. Could it be because of the Virtual Machine?

Comment: @libathos: I tested it on my phone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41519/discussion-between-saji159-and-libathos)

Comment: I have tested your code in Genymotion Emulator It is working. But It is not working on actual device. My device has Android OS 6.0.1 and that emulator has 5.0.0. Can you give some tips or guidance what is the main problem?@saji159